# ReactJs Save function from other file to variable in Component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I have this file
apiService.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = "/getCrimesByCategory/AUTO_THEFT";

export function getAllCrimes() {
    axios.get(url).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        return response;
    })
}
```

and this file:
dataPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MDBDataTable } from 'mdbreact';
import '../App.css';
import { getAllCrimes } from '../controller/ApiService.js';

class DataPage extends Component {

  render() {

    str = getAllCrimes();
    console.log("this is str: " + str)
    return (
      <p>this is str: {str}</p>
    );
  }
}

export default DataPage;
```

the problem is that console.log("this is str: " + getAllCrimes()) returns "this is str: undefined"

I need to return the response of the function to use it later in the dataPage react Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. You have return the data from the `getAllCrimes` function. You can fix this by just adding a **return** in front the API (axios) call.
2. Even if returned, you won't get the data because API calls work in a different way. They work asynchronously. You won't get the data immediately(in your **render** method). But, you can use the advantage of state and lifecycle methods here to solve it.

```
class DataPage extends Component {
  state = {
    str: null, // or "", or {}, or [], based on your need.
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getAllCrimes.then((crimes) => {
      this.setState({
        str: crimes,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { str } = this.state;
    console.log("this is str: " + str);
    return str ? <p>this is str: {str}</p> : <p>You gotta wait</p>;
  }
}
```

I have created a state for the component with `str` as **null** initially.
I just let the component to render, and once it is rendered, the **componetDidMount** will execute.
It calls the API(the function) and once the API returns some value, it will passed to the **then**. (learn `Promises` if not familiar). There, we update the state, which causes a re-render, but now `str` has the data.